# What is the proper way of seeding std::mt19937 with std::chrono::high_resolution_clock inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, random, c++-chrono

First off, hello everyone! This is my first ever question here, so I hope I am not screwing up. I googled a lot before writing here. I am new to coding, to c++ and I am learning it on my own.

Considering that I was told that it is a good practice (i'm probably wrong here) to only seed any Random Engine once, what is the proper / best / more efficient  way of using `std::mt19937` from the random standard library inside a class, seeded by `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()` from the chrono standard library?

I want to use that chrono value, because it changes really fast and it generates a hell of a creepy number. I never considered `std::random_device` because I think it is kinda shady. I'm probably wrong again.

**EDIT:** Most of the times I code and learn on my Android Phone with C4Droid IDE, because I don't have too much free time to sit on a proper computer, so that's why I think `std::random_device` is not really reliable.

I've done it successfully before I knew what a class is, but I am now learning classes and did a lot of trial and error (putting static_casts everywhere, trying const, static, etc, because the code was always giving errors) to get this done:

```cpp
class Deck
{
private:
    std::array<Card, 52> m_card;
    const int m_seed {static_cast<int>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())};

    std::mt19937 m_rng {m_seed};

    int rng(int min, int max)
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> rng{min, max};
    return rng(m_rng);
    }

    void swapCard(Card &a, Card &b)
    {
        Card temp {a};
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

public:

    Deck()
    {
        int index{0};
        for (int iii {0}; iii < Card::CS_MAX; ++iii)
        {
            for (int jjj {0}; jjj < Card::CR_MAX; ++jjj)
            {
                m_card[index] = Card(static_cast<Card::CardSuit>(iii), static_cast<Card::CardRank>(jjj));
                ++index;
            }
        }
    }

    void printDeck() const
    {
    for (int iii {0}; iii < 52; ++iii)
        {
            m_card[iii].printCard();
            if (((iii + 1) % 13 == 0) && iii != 0)
                std::cout << '\n';
            else
                std::cout << ' ';
        }
    }

    void shuffleDeck(int xTimes = 1)
    {
        for (int iii {0}; iii < xTimes; ++iii)
        {
            for (int jjj {0}; jjj < 52; ++jjj)
            {
                swapCard(m_card[jjj], m_card[rng(0, 51)]);
            }
        }
    }

};
```

This works, but I don't know if this is the proper way of doing it. Also, I was told that variables that never change can be made static to be shareable between all objects of the class, but I can not make m_seed static...

I am pretty sure there's a more effective way of doing this. Can you guys help?

Comment: _"Also, I was told that variables that never change can be made static to be shareable between all objects of the class"_ Are you sure you really want that? All class instances would yield the same sequence of cards in that case. Also what do you mean you can't make it `static`, what's the specific problem when doing so?

Comment: "I think it is kinda shady." why? I mean modern CPUs have an instruction for generating a true random number.

Comment: Using time for seeding can make your program predictable to a certain extent.

Comment: I believe `mt19937` has a state size of many thousands of bytes. Even if you have a 64 bit time resolution, you could only seed your PRNG to a very tiny fraction of a percent of it's possible states, no matter how clever you try to be with it. You *can* seed a `mt19937` with only the current time, but it's not a very good seed.

Comment: @Quimby `std::random_device` is known to be broken on `MinGW` compiler. But otherwise it would be my preferred option (I would not support MinGW if they won't make that simple fix).

Comment: @Galik Unfortunately, MinGW's `random_device` implementation is compliant. So while the implementation is bad, it's hard to make a case against it. In principal you should be able to use `std::random_device::entropy();` to decide whether or not it's worthwhile to use it. I'm not sure how widely supported *that* feature is though. Edit : In my opinion, `std::random_device` should be conditionally supported where it can be non-deterministic.

Comment: @Galik That would be a valid reason, I did not know that.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ well, you have a really good point that I never considdered :D

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Well the standard says if the device has a non-determanistic source then `std::random_device` **should** use it. Windows devices have that so so **should** `MinGW`.

Comment: @msmilkshake One approach I like to use is to have a single global PRNG which is only used as a source of entropy to seed thread_local generators.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux could you provide a quick example using the mersenne twister?

Comment: Unrelated, [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)`(m_card.begin(), m_card.end(), m_rng)`. Let's not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @WhozCraig hehe, didn't even know that existed :D thanks for that! but as a code self learning guy, I think trying to achieve things on my own will make me grow and think better. It's all about problem solving, even if it is trivial. I think...

Comment: In general, using time (on its own) as a seed is a bad idea - regardless of the resolution. Two programs may run on the same machine at the same time, within the clock resolution. Or on different machines at the same time. And get identical seeds. Also, clocks can be manipulated by the user. Time may be used as a *component* of a seed, but you really want to throw something else in there as well - `std::random_device` for instance.

Comment: "didn't even know that existed" - then I suggest you dedicate some time to browsing [the algorithm library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) (and more, on [cppreference](https://cppreference.com).

Comment: You may find [std::seed_seq](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq) useful. It has some known flaws (like; there are some numbers it will never generate), but if you throw a few bad entropy sources at it and then seed your generator with the result + some entropy from a few good sources, then you should *generally* be OK (at least for non-cryptographic purposes).

Comment: Lots of great advice here. Thank you guys!

Comment: A bit more on seeding: http://www.pcg-random.org/categories/seeding.html

Comment: you ought to read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device

Comment: This isn’t Code Review, but why should each `Deck` make its own RNG rather than requiring one as an argument to `shuffleDeck` (instead of the mysterious re-shuffling…)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was told that it is a good practice to only seed any Random Engine once

That sounds like sound advice. I'd like to add that you should preferably have exactly one generator per thread since instantiating and seeding it takes time and the standard generators are not thread safe.

> I think `std::random_device` is not really reliable

It should be able to tell you if it is via its `entropy()` function. Zero entropy means its entropy pool is empty or doesn't even exist. You'll get pseudo random numbers from it in the latter case.

> What is the proper way ...

By reading the links in the comments and some other tips, this is what I've collected so far:

- Create a [SeedSequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SeedSequence) class that creates as many seed values as the generator requires. If the entropy in `std::random_device` is zero, combine it as best you can with some other source. I think hashed `time_point` samples taken some time apart could work in combination with `rd()` since 1 changed bit in an input value should ideally change half the bits in the hashed value.
- Create a shared generator that is automatically instantiated and seeded when requested from a (new) thread since since generators aren't thread safe.
- Create distribution templates that inherits from the generator so that all distributions in one thread share the same generator.
- Don't instantiate the distribution more than necessary. If you use the same distribution a lot, keep it.

Here's an attempt at it with comments in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <climits>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// sexmex - A hash function kindly borrowed from Pelle Evensens yet to be published
// work: http://mostlymangling.blogspot.com/
//
// g++ 8.3.1: std::hash<Integer-type> lets the value through as-is (identity)
//            so I'll use this to create proper hash values instead.
template<typename Out = size_t, typename In>
inline std::enable_if_t<sizeof(In) * CHAR_BIT <= 64 &&
                            std::numeric_limits<Out>::is_integer &&
                            std::numeric_limits<In>::is_integer,
                        Out>
sexmex(In v) {
    uint64_t v2 = static_cast<uint64_t>(v); // cast away signedness
    v2 ^= (v2 >> 20) ^ (v2 >> 37) ^ (v2 >> 51);
    v2 *= 0xA54FF53A5F1D36F1ULL; // Fractional part of sqrt(7)
    v2 ^= (v2 >> 20) ^ (v2 >> 37) ^ (v2 >> 51);
    v2 *= 0x510E527FADE682D1ULL; // Fractional part of sqrt(11)
    v2 ^= (v2 >> 20) ^ (v2 >> 37) ^ (v2 >> 51);
    // Discard the high bits if Out is < 64 bits. This particular hash function
    // has not shown any weaknesses in the lower bits in any widely known test
    // suites yet.
    return static_cast<Out>(v2);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class seeder {
public:
    using result_type = std::uint_least32_t;

    // function called by the generator on construction to fill its internal state
    template<class RandomIt>
    void generate(RandomIt Begin, RandomIt End) const noexcept {
        using seed_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*Begin)>;
        std::random_device rd{};

        if(rd.entropy() == 0.) { // check entropy
            // zero entropy, add some
            constexpr auto min = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration::min();
            std::vector<seed_t> food_for_generator(
                static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(Begin, End)));

            for(int stiring = 0; stiring < 10; ++stiring) {
                for(auto& food : food_for_generator) {
                    // sleep a little to ensure a new clock count each iteration
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(min);
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(min);
                    auto cc = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()
                                  .time_since_epoch()
                                  .count();
                    food ^= sexmex<seed_t>(cc);
                    food ^= sexmex<seed_t>(rd());
                }
                stir_buffer(food_for_generator);
            }

            // seed the generator
            for(auto f = food_for_generator.begin(); Begin != End; ++f, ++Begin)
                *Begin = *f;

        } else {
            // we got entropy, use random_device almost as-is but make sure
            // values from rd() becomes seed_t's number of bits and unbiased
            // via sexmex.
            //
            // seed the generator
            for(; Begin != End; ++Begin) *Begin = sexmex<seed_t>(rd());
        }
    }

private:
    template<typename SeedType>
    inline void stir_buffer(std::vector<SeedType>& buf) const noexcept {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < buf.size() * 2; ++i) {
            buf[i % buf.size()] += static_cast<SeedType>(
                sexmex(buf[(i + buf.size() - 1) % buf.size()] + i));
        }
    }
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct shared_generator {
    // we want one instance shared between all instances of uniform_dist per thread
    static thread_local seeder ss;
    static thread_local std::mt19937 generator;
};

thread_local seeder shared_generator::ss{};
thread_local std::mt19937 shared_generator::generator(ss);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// a distribution template for uniform distributions, both int and real
template<typename T>
class uniform_dist : shared_generator {
public:
    uniform_dist(T low, T high) : distribution(low, high) {}

    // make instances callable
    inline T operator()() { return distribution(generator); }

private:
    template<class D>
    using dist_t =
        std::conditional_t<std::is_integral_v<D>, std::uniform_int_distribution<D>,
                           std::uniform_real_distribution<D>>;

    dist_t<T> distribution;
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void thread_func() {
    uniform_dist<int> something(0, 10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) std::cout << something() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    // all distributions sharing the same generator:
    uniform_dist<size_t> card_picker(0, 51);
    uniform_dist<int16_t> other(-32768, 32767);
    uniform_dist<float> fd(-1000.f, 1000.f);
    uniform_dist<double> dd(-1., 1.);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) std::cout << card_picker() << "\n";
    std::cout << "--\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) std::cout << other() << "\n";
    std::cout << "--\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) std::cout << fd() << "\n";
    std::cout << "--\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) std::cout << dd() << "\n";
    // in the thread function, a new generator will be created and seeded.
    std::thread t(thread_func);
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: I just countered that downvote. Well I don't know what templates are yet. :) gotta learn more. I'll give that a proper read when I get home.

Comment: Thanks! I've now replaced `hasher` with a good hash function but will probably tweak the seeding when there's no entropy in `rd()` a little further later.

Comment: This is complex to me but seems like a great answer and a lot of effort put into it to help me! Thanks for this.

Comment: @msmilkshake Thanks! If you'd like me to put more comments in where it's unclear, I'll try to make it better. The main part of the answer isn't in the example code though. If you implement something according to the set of advice you can just glance at the entropy-adding stuff to make something that works for you. Having a good hash function is key for this to work though. The one above is very (overkill) good but even though I see what it's doing it can't even begin to explain it.